# Android spinner onItemSelected called multiple times after screen rotation

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a layout with three spinners. They differ in the option presented in the drop-down.
In my `onCreateView` I have a method to setup the spinners. Inside that method I have something like this:

```
  mySpinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.my_spinner);
  ArrayAdapter<String> mySpinner =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.background,
                    new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.spinner_one_data))));
  mySpinner.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_text);
  mySpinner.setAdapter(mySpinner);
  mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

As I said, my other two spinners are almost the same but with different options.

I know that `onItemSelected` is called once for every spinner in a "first setup" so I have a flag to prevent this problem. With this flag solution, my spinners are working as expected.

The problem is when I select in each spinner an option and then rotate the screen. Now, `onItemSelected` is called 6 times instead the 3 times that I was expecting (I've set a flag to manage this situation of the 3 times calling).

Why Is it happening and hoe should I handle this?

Comment: Have you handled screen rotation in your mainefest

Comment: No. I do not want to change the manifest. Should I do that?

Comment: Not changing the mainefest but adding a handler to tell the app not to redraw the elements on orientation change otherwise redrawing the elements will fire the methods which I assume is what happens in your case

Comment: Google this. On orientation change handler - android mainefest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution that is working for me.

I have the `3` spinners so `onItemSelected` is called `3` times at the initial spinner setup. To avoid `onItemSelected` from firing a method in the initial setup I've created a counter so `onItemSelected` only fires the method accordingly the counter value.

I've realized that in my situation, if a rotated the screen, `onItemSelected` is fired again the `3` times, plus a time for each spinner that is not in the position `0`.

An example:

I have the `3` spinners and the user changes `2` of them to one of the available option other then position `0` so he ends up with a situation like this:

```
First spinner - > Item 2 selected
Second spinner -> Item 0 selected (no changes)
Third spinner -> Item 1 selected
```

Now, wen I rotate the screen, `onItemSelected` will be fired `3` times for the initial spinner setup plus `2` times for the spinners that aren't at position `0`.

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    int changedSpinners = 0;
    if (spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition() != 0) {
        changedSpinners += 1;
    }
    if (spinner2.getSelectedItemPosition() != 0) {
        changedSpinners += 1;
    }
    if (spinner3.getSelectedItemPosition() != 0) {
        changedSpinners += 1;
    }
    outState.putInt("changedSpinners", changedSpinners);
}
```

I've saved the state in `onSaveInstanceState` and then, in `onCreateView` I checked if `savedInstanceState != null` and if so, extracted `changedSpinners` from the bundle and updated my counter to act accordingly.

Answer (score 36):

In general, I've found that there are many different events that can trigger the onItemSelected method, and it is difficult to keep track of all of them. Instead, I found it simpler to use an OnTouchListener to only respond to user-initiated changes.

Create your listener for the spinner:

```
public class SpinnerInteractionListener implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, View.OnTouchListener {

    boolean userSelect = false;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        userSelect = true;
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        if (userSelect) { 
            // Your selection handling code here
            userSelect = false;
        }
    }

}
```

Add the listener to the spinner as both an OnItemSelectedListener and an OnTouchListener:

```
SpinnerInteractionListener listener = new SpinnerInteractionListener();
mSpinnerView.setOnTouchListener(listener);
mSpinnerView.setOnItemSelectedListener(listener);
```

Comment: Best answer to handle android's worst widget.

Comment: You're a hero. I've been on this for ages. If I could give you 100 up votes I would

Comment: Excellent!! One of the elegant solution in so!

Comment: This doesn't handle the click for item at position 0.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Andres Q.'s answer...  If you are using Java 8 you can do this with fewer lines of code by making use of lambda expressions.  This method also forgoes the need to create a separate class in order to implement onTouchListener

```
Boolean spinnerTouched; //declare this as an instance or class variable

spinnerTouched = false;
yourSpinner.setOnTouchListener((v,me) -> {spinnerTouched = true; v.performClick(); return false;});

yourSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        if(spinnerTouched){
            //do your stuff here
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        //nothing selected
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What about just to check if fragment is in resumed state? Somethink like this:

```
private AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener mFilterListener = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (isResumed()) {
              //your code
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    };

@Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //set mFilterListener
}
```

It eliminates the rotation problem and also the first setup problem. No flags etc. I was having the same problem with TextWatchers and found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6119815/9317258) with comment, which inspired me for this solution.